# How do I use doxygen with vcpkg/cmake?

Tags: doxygen, vcpkg

I want to use doxygen with my project to generate documentation.

All "normal" dependencies of my project are managed by vcpkg and I was hoping that I can use doxygen this way as well, although it is not a lib that I link against, but a tool that I process my files with.

- There seems to be some need for this, as [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/2818) seems to be posted and some solution is merged.
- When I dig further I found that there is a function called [vcpkg_find_acquire_program](https://vcpkg.readthedocs.io/en/latest/maintainers/vcpkg_find_acquire_program/) that can specifically be called with doxygen argument. However, all examples are using `portfile.cmake` which my project does not have.

In my project I use:

- vcpkg.json that acts as a manifest file. I specify the project name, version, dependencies. But I cannot put doxygen in the dependency list, because there is no doxygen portfile
- CMakeLists.txt where I can specify that I require doxygen, but cmake won't manage downloading/installing it for me. It's vcpkg's job.
- CMakeSettings.json where I specify build configurations

...and that is about it in terms of project configuration. So, where should I put that vcpkg_find_acquire_program? Or is there a different way?